# Hibernate does not create foreign key constraint

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

The question seems duplicate but I have not found a solution yet.

I am using spring boot data jpa + mysql, and here is my classes:

```
@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
@Table(name = "Question")
public class Question {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  private int id;

  @Column(length = 128)
  private String name;

  @OneToMany(mappedBy = "question", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
  private List<QuestionAnswerMapping> questionAnswerMapping;
}
```

And

```
@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
@Table(name = "Answer")
public class Answer {
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  private int id;

  @Column(length = 255)
  private String displayText;

  @OneToMany(mappedBy = "answer")
  private List<QuestionAnswerMapping> questionAnswerMapping;
}
```

And

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Question_Answer_Mapping")
public class QuestionAnswerMapping {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  private int id;

  @ManyToOne
  @JoinColumn(name="questionId", nullable = false /*, referencedColumnName="id" , foreignKey=@ForeignKey(name="FK_Question", value=ConstraintMode.CONSTRAINT)*/)
  /*    @JoinColumns(value = { @JoinColumn(name="questionId",referencedColumnName="id",foreignKey=@ForeignKey(value=ConstraintMode.CONSTRAINT)) }) */
  private Question question;

  @ManyToOne
  @JoinColumn(name="answerId", nullable = false /*, referencedColumnName="id", foreignKey=@ForeignKey(name="FK_Answer", value=ConstraintMode.CONSTRAINT)*/)
  /*    @JoinColumns(value = { @JoinColumn(name="answerId",referencedColumnName="id",foreignKey=@ForeignKey(value=ConstraintMode.CONSTRAINT)) }) */
  private Answer answer;

}
```

and application.yml

```
--- 
spring:
  profiles: local

  datasource:
    url: jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test?useSSL=false
    username: root

  jpa:
    generate-ddl: true
    show-sql: true
    hibernate:
      naming:
        physical-strategy:     org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.PhysicalNamingStrategyStandardImpl
    properties:
      hibernate:
        dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
        ddl-auto: create-drop
```

and These are create statements I have copied after creating tables by ORM.

```
CREATE TABLE `question` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(128) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci;


CREATE TABLE `answer` (
 `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `displayText` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci;


CREATE TABLE `question_answer_mapping` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `answerId` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `questionId` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `FKpjg76y4ofqmvfmbujphnqyq1y` (`answerId`),
  KEY `FK2mbyguxt74rwhv1n1t11wi3fl` (`questionId`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci;
```

All commented out parts are combinations of my efforts to create FK key on database schema which falied.

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/myisam-storage-engine.html: What does the table say about foreign key support?

Comment: @JBNizet Thank you, I did not pay attention to engine :)

Comment: @JBNizet If  I change a dialect to MySQLInnoDBDialect, it complains about creating foreign keys and says mapping table do not exists.

Comment: If you have a question about an error, edit your question, and post the complete, and exact error message. Note that, in the latest Hibernate versions, MySQLInnoDBDialect is deprecated. Read the javadoc and use the appropriate dialect, with the appropriate options.

Answer (score 3):

Per @JBNizet comment, I used wrong dialect :)

```
org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL55Dialect
```

Answer (score 3):

In the application.properties:

```
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL55Dialect
```

Answer (score 0):

make sur that:

```
<property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL55Dialect</property>
```

is in your hibernate.cfg.xml